# This tag is a [load] of garbage

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

[load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/load) is not meaningful enough on its own, and should therefore be removed. That should only happen after the relevant questions have been re-tagged to something like [cpu-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpu-load).

Comment: Probably lots should be re-tagged to [onload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onload).

Comment: Suggested title: "This tag is a [load] of garbage"

Answer (score 4):

I agree, having a quick look through [load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/load) tags, it's clear that it's misused a lot and adds no value.

Suggestions for re-tagging:

- [cpu-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpu-load) for actual processing load questions
- [onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onload) JavaScript questions
- [pageload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pageload) general web page loading questions (HTML/PHP/ASP etc)
- [load-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/load-testing) self explanatory
- [assembly-loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly-loading) self explanatory
- [dynamic-script-loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-script-loading) web script loading

Please feel free to add further suggestions if you have any either directly or in comments and I will update accordingly.

Comment: mm... onload is a JS specific function. You think we need one for each function?

Comment: @Braiam that's true, have updated that suggested retag. What do you mean by "for each function?"

Comment: That if we are going to have a tag for one function, why not having a tag for all the others?

Answer (score 3):

The definition of the tag says it's about "In computing (typically UNIX), load is a measure of the amount of computational work that a computer system performs." Clearly as Kara points out many are about `onload` or other things.  The tag term itself leads to confusion, and thus the mess of stuff under it.

Answer (score -8):

Perhaps the definition should be changed?

In some programming languages (at least MATLAB) `load` is the word for loading files, as opposed to `save`. I feel like it would be meaningfull to keep the tag for that.

Comment: No. The fact that it means lots of different things is lots of different contexts makes it useless as a tag.